# IdentityServer 4 ASP .NET Core MVC Ajax Call redirects to authorize endpoint if page is idle for several minutes

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have an ASP NET CORE MVC Application using Identity Server 4 oidc hybrid flow as authenticator.

When I load a page, if the user is not authenticated, it calls the IS4 authorize endpoint to log in.

After the authentication process, when the page is loaded, if I leave the page idle for more than 30 minutes and then press a button that perfoms an AJAX call to the ASP MVC App, it wants to make a redirect to the IS4 authorize endpoint again. (Common XHR Cors error)

I cannot find the reason of this issue. The IS4 access token has a lifetime of 2 hours. Also, in my MVC app I added IS4 AutomaticTokenManagement, so if the token is expired, it takes a new one automatically using the refresh token.

Also, I set the ASP MVC App Cookie with a sliding expiration of one day.

**I dont know why authentication is lost.**

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies.Mvc";
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
            })
            .AddCookie("Cookies.Mvc", options =>
            {
                // Configure the client application to use sliding sessions
                options.SlidingExpiration = true;
                // Expire the session of 15 minutes of inactivity
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
            })      
            .AddAutomaticTokenManagement()
            .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
            {                    
                options.SignInScheme = "Cookies.Mvc";                    
                options.Authority = MyAuthorityAuthServerSettings.Authority;
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = MyAuthorityAuthServerSettings.RequiredHttpsMetadata;
                options.ClientId = MyAuthorityOpenIDSettings.ClientId;
                options.ClientSecret = MyAuthorityOpenIDSettings.ClientSecret;
                options.SaveTokens = true;
                options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
                options.ResponseType = "code id_token";
                options.Scope.Add(MyAuthorityOpenIDSettings.Scope);
                options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
                options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(MyAuthorityClaims.UserId, MyAuthorityClaims.UserId);
                options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(MyAuthorityClaims.UserName, MyAuthorityClaims.UserName);
                options.UseTokenLifetime = false;                    
            });
```

**What could be the reason that authentication is lost after the page is idle for some time? If I load the same page in another navigator tab, it does not redirect to authenticate as its already authenticated. It seems to be that it only happens after its idle and using an ajax call.**

UPDATE:

Added log in / log out code:

```
        [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult Login()
    {
        return Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties
        {
            RedirectUri = "/Home/Index"
        }, "oidc");
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult Logout()
    {
        return SignOut(new AuthenticationProperties
        {
            RedirectUri = "/Home/Index"
        }, "Cookies.Mvc", "oidc");
    }
```

Comment: Are you able to share details of the actual cookie that gets output and if possible the `AuthenticationProperties` within it - you may need to call `AuthenticateAsync("Cookies.Mvc");` to get that.

Comment: @mackie I added the configuration code.

Comment: what is your identity token lifetime (within your client configuration in idsrv)? for me it's easier to set `options.UseTokenLifetime = true;` (it's `false` by default) and avoid the settings in `AddCookie`